# Should I copy ntuser.dat when I move a user profile?

Tags: windows-7, user-profiles

When I copy a user profile from one hard drive to another one (I'm replacing the HDD), do I need to copy `ntuser.dat` and `ntuser.ini` ?

I'm asking because I wonder if it doesn't contain the user's program preferences for certain applications.

Comment: What's unclear?  A user profile folder contains the ntuser files; I am asking whether to copy them along with the profile's folders.  The profile is not corrupted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Do I need to copy `NTUSER.DAT` and `ntuser.ini`?

`NTUSER.DAT` contains the user's program preferences and `ntuser.ini` is used to set up user roaming profile components, so both should be copied along with the rest of the user profile.

**`NUSER.DAT`:**

- `NTUSER.DAT` is stored in `C:\Users\<username>`
- It contains the entire contents of the `HKEY_LOCAL_USER` branch of the Registry, which is the user's personalised settings for much of the installed software, including Windows itself.
- When the user logs on, `NTUSER.DAT` is merged with the computer's registry, and becomes the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` branch of the registry tree.
- `NTUSER.DAT` is locked whenever the user is logged on.

**`ntuser.ini`:**

Is used to set up user roaming profile components.